# Blender is Crashing Finding Missing FIles

Tags: texturing, linked-data

I am trying to relink some Kitbash3D models to their textures. Using "External Data/Find Missing Files" is reliably crashing Blender release (2.82a) and the beta (2.83) every time. The models are large-ish - all the textures together are 1.2 Gb and the blend file is 220 Mb. But I have deleted half of them, and I have a decent system - 16Gb of RAM Ryzen processor, RTX2060 Super. I'm using Linux....I do have a PC (128 Gb RAM) and a Mac...I'll give that go.

Can anyone suggest a work around or point to what the problem could be?

Answer (score 1):

I have the same issue, possibly with the exact same models - I downloaded a couple of the free minikits they had and it crashes whenever I try to find the missing files.

Overall, to fix it I am deleting all the groups except one of them, then saving that group to a separate file and doing the find textures fix. It manages one group at a time with no issue.

I also ran the "report missing textures" then opened the console and saw that KitBash defaulted their texture directory to K:\KB3D\KB3DTextures, so another workaround would be to map a network drive as K: then recreate that directory structure and copy the textures there (this would be the quickest fix but also means you have to map the drive to use them). I am new to Blender, so I am not sure, but there may then be a way to move the textures to the correct directory after doing this. If there is, please let me know :)

[image: Missing Textures]

Answer (score 0):

I am pretty sure that the problem was simply too little memory. Low memory is a very reliable way to crash any program, and I was having this issue with a number of other very big environments. The solution is to increase Virtual RAM if you cannot any more RAM for the computer, or don't want to. Some of my projects are close to 50 Gbs in size including virtual RAM.

Answer (score 0):

Had this problem today with a file size that was no larger than 200 mb, and my RAM wouldn't even come close to maxing out. What worked for me for "Find Missing Files" was turning off all my layers, and turning on one layer from the missing file. It helped that all my layers came from the same kit. Once that one smaller layer loaded the missing file, save, and everything else was good to go.